# External evaluation failed

Tags: python

Can someone help me with the ExternalEvaluation with Python. I think the problem is that for some reason my Python is not registered due to the error "MissingDependencies". A screen shot of the error is attached here.
[image]

Comment: Did you set it up? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html

Comment: Yes, I did. My Python was installed using Anaconda.

Comment: So if you start _the very same Python_ that you tried to register, then `import zmq` works without errors? Make sure you start the same executable that you are trying to register.

Comment: BTW on my machine Anaconda Python installed into my home directory, not in /Library/Frameworks  (I don't remember if I had a choice, but /Library/Frameworks doesn't seem right if you are indeed using Anaconda Python)